# Distinct based on collection

Tags: sql, t-sql

Does anybody know how to distinct by items in child table?
I am not sure if it is possible but maybe somebody can clarify that.

For example I have 2 tables: A and B (1 to many).
I need to join them and select rows from A only once if B has the same items for corresponding A-row.

I need to do it on SQL server side because I want to have paging there using ROW_NUMBER.

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A] ([ID] int NOT NULL, [Name] varchar(Max) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B] ([ID] int NOT NULL, [A_ID] int NOT NULL, [Name] varchar(Max) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO A VALUES (1, 'A1')
INSERT INTO A VALUES (2, 'A2')
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 1, 'B1')
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 1, 'B2')
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 2, 'B1')
INSERT INTO B VALUES (4, 2, 'B2')
```

This should return only A1, B1, B2 thinking that A1 and A2 are equals by their B1 and B2.

Let me know if it is clear now.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/897704/1/0

Comment: How can inner join solve it?

Comment: Man, I need to select distinct A by B sub-items. So all B rows for equal A should be the same. If you have A = a1 and B = [b1, b2] then a2 will be the same ONLY if B for a2 also will contain [b1, b2] not [b1, b2, b3] or just [b1]. Is it more clear?

Comment: You do not understand... You just suggest me to cross 2 tables. I need distinct based on sub-items in B... read my previous comment. I have updated it.

Comment: I updated original question. I have not made any PK, FK... I guess it is clear that A_ID is FK for A.ID...

Comment: What do you expect as output?  I am a little confused by your statement regarding this.

Comment: It is written in my question: "This should return only A1, B1, B2 thinking that A1 and A2 are equals by their B1 and B2."

Comment: do you expect them to be in separate columns or separate rows? How do you decide whether you want A1 or A2?

Comment: It should be 1 row [A1, B1, B2] or [A2, B1, B2].. but only one... And any of A1 or A2 can be selected, let's guess - just first.. If it is necessary I will add some logic to select between A1 and A2 later (it does not matter for now). If it is [A3, B1] then it should be another row. So distinct will have 2 rows A1 and A3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick. I threw in a little extra `CHECKSUM_AGG` magic so that if you have a really big table, it will still perform very well.

```
WITH Grouped AS (
   SELECT
      A_ID,
      GroupID = Checksum_Agg(Checksum(B.Name))
   FROM
      B
   GROUP BY
      B.A_ID
), DistinctA AS (
   SELECT G1.A_ID
   FROM
      Grouped G1
   WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM Grouped G2
         WHERE
            G1.GroupID = G2.GroupID
            AND G1.A_ID > G2.A_ID
            AND NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT *
               FROM
                  (SELECT * FROM B B1 WHERE G1.A_ID = B1.A_ID) B1
                  FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM B B2 WHERE G2.A_ID = B2.A_ID ) B2
                     ON B1.Name = B2.Name
               WHERE
                    B1.A_ID IS NULL
                    OR B2.A_ID IS NULL
            )
      )
)
SELECT
   A_ID = A.ID,
   AName = A.Name,
   B_ID = B.ID,
   BName = B.Name
FROM
   DistinctA DA
   INNER JOIN A
      ON DA.A_ID = A.ID
   INNER JOIN B
      ON A.ID = B.A_ID
;
```

**[See this query live in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52812/1)**

Please note that the `CHECKSUM_AGG` by itself will NOT guarantee correctness. Actual correctness is guaranteed by the `FULL JOIN` part of the query, that checks for any `Name`s in the `B` table that don't match (one or the other is NULL for that group of `A_ID`s). But the `CHECKSUM_AGG` acts as a hashing function so that the `FULL JOIN` only has to compare a very few potential duplicates, instead of every other group of `A_ID`s in the entire `B` table.

A few of things I see:

- It is not good to name columns just `ID`. Then you have to alias them all over the place. The column `A_ID` should be the same in every table, including `A`.
- I realize this was just an example, but underscores are the bane of professional SQL writers. They take just as many keys to type as PascalCase, but require moving the weakest finger off the home row and two keys to the right. `WhateverID` is far superior to `WHATEVER_ID`. Even `WHATEVERID` is tolerable.
- It sounds like your `B` table could use another table to join to, to look up the `Name` value. If two rows in `B` with the same name mean the same thing, then the chance of one of them having a misspelling becomes a very real proposition. Instead, `B` may need to join to another table that has all the unique names and provides an ID.
- Your `B` table may not need an `ID` column (as show in in this example). In many cases, even if individual B rows are going to be accessed via a key, it can be better for them to reached via the `A_ID` and the `Name` (or better, an ID representing the name). Of course, I don't know what the data in these tables actually is, and there are many times when a surrogate key is appropriate. In the case that B is really a many-to-many join table, even if it has a few extra columns, most of the time such tables should *not* have a surrogate key.

One more thing: if multiple columns in the `B` table, besides `Name`, are needed to know if the row is a duplicate compared to another `A`'s `B` row, then that can be accomplished. Please let me know if this is the case.

It would actually be helpful if your data was meaningful in the real world. Exposing a tiny bit about the business objects can hardly reveal anything truly private, and it helps people who are answering you to answer better when your example data is more concrete. It also actually helps you understand better and faster the answers you get--since my above query is 100% abstract, it will be hard to grok.

Another note: I sure wish SQL Server would provide `DISUNION` to complement `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, and `EXCEPT`. Then that would be another option for the part of the query where I used `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: 1) CHECKSUM_AGG really makes magic, thanks.. I tried to figure custom aggregate but I avoid CLR functions. 2) Solution works, but we have to wrap all by distinct based on A because for now there are 2 rows for A1 (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/897704/3) 3) ID is OK because I can access it by A.ID or B.ID and in addition I am using ORM and views (if necessary), other suggestion are not applicable (as you said it is test data).

Comment: Maxim I made some edits to clean up the query (for example, the `Grouped` CTE doesn't need to select from `A`). I still think my comments about `A.AID` and `B.BID` instead of `A.ID` and `B.ID` apply--the main point is not about accessing those but about making the columns the same in every table they're represented in.

Comment: I understand your point of view... But for me from point of view of source code it is much more universally to create base class allowing us to always have ID as single primary key column (field of entity to reference it). After some experiments with MySQL Cluster and sharding I have selected that design and it worked pretty well in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate query. Shorter than ErikE's, but may break when you try to add additional columns.

Essentially though, the inner query concatenates all the values of B.Name into a single string (ie "B1,B2," etc).  If all the parts of B are the same, then you can GROUP BY in the outer query. As you mentioned above the choice of A.Name is arbitrary at this stage, so I have done MIN to get the first.

```
SELECT MIN(sub1.Name), sub1.conc
FROM (SELECT A.Name, (SELECT [Name]+','
                      FROM [b]
                      WHERE B.A_ID = A.ID
                      FOR XML PATH('')) conc
      FROM [A]) sub1
GROUP BY sub1.conc
```

Comment: I thought about that option. But what is maximum length of concatenated string (if B has a lot of children)? Another issue - order of values - for example for some reason it can B2B1. So I guess we need to take care about sorting. I guess that additional columns should not be a problem because we can join to A.ID over that query. To decide which solution is better we need to test both. But I guess that ErikE solution is more universal and faster.

Comment: Once there's about 8k worth of Names, I think the XML version will not perform as well. I'd be interested in any performance testing that you do. I'd also be interested in a query that does the full job of showing the selected `A.ID, A.Name, B.ID, B.Name`.

Comment: @Maxim An ORDER BY could be used on the XML select.  The whole XML Select can be replaced by GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL and other databases have similar functions.  As far as performance goes I assumed that the grouping of B's would contain a small to medium number of values.  If you are looking to exclude additional parents that have exactly the same children as another and if the number of children is potentially in the thousands or millions then you are going to have issues with performance, because either way you are going to be crossing 2 very large datasets.

Comment: The `Checksum_agg` helps the thousands scenario perform better than you'd expect, though I'm skeptical about millions. :)